# Which JFrog repository need to choose for save PDF files?

Tags: python, repository, artifactory

I want to **save/store pdf** files in JFrog repository from python appliation. For this I installed JFrog community version on my local system. But I confused which JFrog repository need to choose for save PDF files.

[image]

Please guide me on this. I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Artifactory has [Generic Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-GenericRepositories) that should be used to upload packages of any type that is not supported by one of the other repository types. In your case - anything that's not Java should go into a generic repository.

Note - You can create many generic repositories for different usages. Don't have to use the same one.